# How to get multiple query results in same request handler function with hapi js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, hapi.js

I have hapi js server route handler method and it has knexjs select query with limit the result set to 10 per page. but in that same reply need to get the totalPages count too. I included separate function to get the total post count. but 'totalPages' value is not displaying in the json result. Can I know how to get total query count to 'totalPages' variable before execute 'getOperation' method and include that value to 'getOperation' reply section.

````
server.route({
    path: options.basePath + '/posts/byCategory/{category}/list/page/{page}',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: async  (request, reply) => {
        const page= request.params.page;
        const category = request.params.category;
        var soffset=(page-1)+"0";
        var offset=Number(soffset);

        var totalPages;

        totalPages = await server.app.knex('posts').where({
            category_english_name: category
        }).select().then((results) => {
            results.length;
        });   

        const getOperation = server.app.knex('posts').where({
            category_english_name: category
        }).select().limit(10).offset(offset).then((results) => {
            //totalPages=Math.ceil(results.length/10);

            if (!results || results.length === 0) {
                reply({
                    error: true,
                    errMessage: 'No result found',
                });
            }
            reply({
                page:page,
                dataCount: results.length,
                offset:offset,
                total_pages: totalPages,
                results: results,
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            reply('server-side error');
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this question.

we need to create a function with return the first query result. then we need to call that function and the returned value should be assigned to const variable in handle function. then we can add the first query result to our reply.

function with parameter to execute first query

```
function getAllPageCount(category) {
    return server.app.knex('posts').where({
        category_english_name: category
    }).select().then((results) => {

           return results.length;
        });

};
```

Then call that function before second query in handler

```
server.route({
    path: options.basePath + '/posts/byCategory/{category}/list/page/{page}',
    method: 'GET',

    handler: async  (request, reply) => {
        const page= request.params.page;
        const category = request.params.category;
        var soffset=(page-1)+"0";
        var offset=Number(soffset);
        var tot;

        const pageCount = await getAllPageCount(category).catch((err) => { throw err }) 

        console.log("pageCount "+pageCount);

        const getOperation = server.app.knex('posts').where({
            category_english_name: category
        }).select().limit(10).offset(offset).then((results) => {
            //totalPages=Math.ceil(results.length/10);

            if (!results || results.length === 0) {
                reply({
                    error: true,
                    errMessage: 'No result found',
                });
            }
            reply({
                page:page,
                dataCount: results.length,
                offset:offset,
                total_pages: pageCount,
                results: results,
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            reply('server-side error');
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```